# De-beveling plane angles

Tags: bevel

Good evening everyone, I was trying to work on a project while I encountered a problem that I don't know how to solve. I was wondering if it was possible to de-bevel this plane and make the angle straight to 90 degrees. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!
[image: plane to de-bevel]

Comment: Can you add an image of it in Edit mode so that we can see the vertices please?

Comment: If you are not using Bevel modifier I don't think there is other way than Disolve unwanted vertices and manually move with G,G along edge with Snap to vertex enabled, than Merge by distance.

Comment: I tried that and it worked, thank you so much @vklidu!!

Comment: Great if that helped (I forget to mention Alt to extend G/G move, but if it worked you discovered that by your self I guess :)